# Printing full calendar invitation?

Tags: macos, printing, apple-mail, calendar.app

I use OS X Mail and iCal connected to my company's MS Exchange server. Sometimes a co-worker sends a calendar invitation (using Outlook) with lots of agenda details in it. I'm trying to find a good way to print that.

iCal has an option to print the day's events in list format, but the output is in two columns and a few of the lines write over each other and are completely unreadable.

If I try to print the invitation as it came to me in Mail, the output has an iCal icon showing the attachment -- not the contents of the attachment.

So, short of copy/paste into TextEdit, Word, etc, is there a clean way to print this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been remedied in iCal in OS X Lion (10.7).

On the print dialog, choose "selected events" instead of the day/week/month view.